# Unable to draw Primitives on Texture in SharpDX

Tags: c#, rendering, directx-11, sharpdx

I have a little problem with rendering in my SharpDX Direct11 App.

I had being tested rendering scene on a texture, and then draw this texture on backBuffer... but unfortunately renderTexture do not contains primitives which should be drawn. Texture is only filled by color.

Whole project on github: https://github.com/Kordi3112/SharpDXTest11

Main code part with rendering methods:

```
public override void Render()
    {
        //Camera
        var proj = Matrix.OrthoLH(3 * Form.Bounds.Width / Form.Bounds.Height, 3, 0.01f, 100f);
        var view = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, -10), new Vector3(0, 0, 20), Vector3.UnitY);
        var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(view, proj);

        var world = Matrix.Identity;

        var worldViewProj = world * viewProj;
        worldViewProj.Transpose();

        //Update wvp matrix
        Context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, ContantBuffer);

        DrawOnTexture();

        //Set BackBuffer as render target
        Context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthView, renderView);

        // Clear views
        Context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
        Context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Pink);

        //Set TextureColor Shader
        Effect2.ApplyShader(Context);

        //Set Buffers
        Context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer2, Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionColorTexture>(), 0));
        Context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);

        //Set Texture to Shader
        Context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, RenderTexture.ShaderResourceView);

        //Draw 
        Context.DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);

        // Present!
        SwapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
    }

    private void DrawOnTexture()
    {
        //Set Color Shader
        Effect1.ApplyShader(Context);

        //Set Buffers
        Context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionColor>(), 0));
        Context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);

        //Set Target
        RenderTexture.SetRenderTarget(Context, depthView);

        //Clear Targets - Green Bgound
        RenderTexture.ClearRenderTarget(Context, depthView, 0, 1, 0, 1);

        //Draw on RenderTarget
        Context.DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);

    }
```

After call: *Context.DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);* in *private void DrawOnTexture()* primitive should be drawn.

[What this code above do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HO4z.png)

[What i wanted to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u9QK.png)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Not sure how the `Matrix.Multiply` and the * are implemented, but make sure your matrices are being multiplied in the correct order. Usually for MVP you would multiply in reverse order Projection * View * Model. Or in your case model would be `world`. Next make sure your camera is facing the right direction, if you're attempting to draw two triangles (rectangle) they may be culled because they are not facing the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the problem is not matrix or camera. When i will modify code to render primitive directly on backBuffer then its drawing normaly.

```
    public override void Render()
    {
        //Camera
        var proj = Matrix.OrthoLH(3 * Form.Bounds.Width / Form.Bounds.Height, 3, 0.01f, 100f);
        var view = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0, 0, -10), new Vector3(0, 0, 20), Vector3.UnitY);
        var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(view, proj);

        var world = Matrix.Identity;

        var worldViewProj = world * viewProj;
        worldViewProj.Transpose();

        //Update wvp matrix
        Context.UpdateSubresource(ref worldViewProj, ContantBuffer);

        //DrawOnTexture();

        //Set BackBuffer as render target
        Context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(depthView, renderView);

        // Clear views
        Context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);
        Context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Pink);

        //Set Color Shader
        Effect1.ApplyShader(Context);

        //Set Buffers
        Context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(VertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<VertexPositionColor>(), 0));
        Context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(IndexBuffer, Format.R32_UInt, 0);

        //Set Texture to Shader
        //Context.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, RenderTexture.ShaderResourceView);

        //Draw 
        Context.DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);

        // Present!
        SwapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
    }
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub2oS.png)

Vertex Buffers declaration:

```
//Position Color
        VertexBuffer = Buffer.Create(Device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[] {
            new VertexPositionColor(new Vector4(-1, -1, 0, 1), Color.Red.ToVector4()),
            new VertexPositionColor(new Vector4(-1, 1, 0, 1), Color.Green.ToVector4()),
            new VertexPositionColor(new Vector4(1, 1, 0, 1), Color.Blue.ToVector4()),
            new VertexPositionColor(new Vector4(1, -1, 0, 1), Color.Yellow.ToVector4())
        });

        //Position Color Texture
        VertexBuffer2 = Buffer.Create(Device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, new[] {
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector4(-1, -1, 0, 1), Color.White.ToVector4(), new Vector2(0,1)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector4(-1, 1, 0, 1), Color.White.ToVector4(),new Vector2(0,0)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector4(1, 1, 0, 1), Color.White.ToVector4(),new Vector2(1,0)),
            new VertexPositionColorTexture(new Vector4(1, -1, 0, 1), Color.White.ToVector4(),new Vector2(1,1))
        });

        IndexBuffer = Buffer.Create(Device, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, new[] {
            0,1,2,
            0,2,3
        });
```